# Samsung Dishwasher Leaving Brown Residue on Silverware

Tags: plumbing, kitchens, dishwasher

I am looking to fix a relatively new Samsung Dishwasher. The dishwasher works fine for the most part, but it consistently leaves a brown sticky residue on our silverware. I have tried to clean the dishwasher, the dishwasher filter itself, run on high heat settings, use citric acid, vinegar, pretty much anything you can find on Google. My dishes come out great, it's just the silverware that comes out with this brown gunk on it. (We do rinse dishes and silverware before putting them into the dishwasher)

Are there any additional steps that I can take to troubleshoot this?

Also, could be related, but the dishwasher also emits a wet dog smell when running.

Any guidance is much appreciated on this as I'm a new homeowner.

Comment: Are you mixing silver plated items with base metal items?

Comment: @PhilFreedenberg That's a good question. I have hand-me-downs from my parents, but recently bought steel knives from Amazon right before moving into my new place. My table knives(both old and new) are usually the only ones with the gunk on them. Do you think the difference in metals is the reason for the brown gunk? It's a sticky gunk, not rust.

Comment: It seems that some test runs would be appropriate to see if you can narrow down the cause. Do a load of dishes with only the hand-me-down knives, then another with only the new ones. See if you can identify when the gunk appears.

Comment: Are there two locations for silverware? i.e. tray at top and baskets below? I would try to move the silverware to another location in the DW. That will tell you if the issue is the metal in the silverware or the location in the DW. Also you should [take our tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll best know how to participate here with upvotes for helpful info and checks for accepted answers.

Comment: After experimenting, I still haven't figured out the cause. I've tried washing the knives separately from my new knifes, new knives only, and tried washing them in different locations, washing with citric acid, washing on high heat, washing with sanitation mode on, and more. No luck. Not sure where to go next.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that it seems to be something high protein on them like eggs, mayonnaise, or yogurt. If those aren't basically pre-washed I get that brown sticky residue on them

Comment: Peanut butter will also leave a brown sticky residue if not rinsed off.